# Changing the value of an external variable

Tags: c, extern

We have in File1.c

```
int arr[10];
```

And in File2.c

```
extern int *arr;

int main()

{
   arr[0]=10;
   return 0;
}
```

What are the problems that can occur with this and why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An array isn't a pointer.  The memory access will be wrong.

In `File1.c`, you have the memory layout:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
+ 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
^
arr
```

In `File2.c`, you've told the compiler you have the memory layout:

```
+-------+
|  ptr  |
+-------+
^
arr
```

where the pointer presumably points somewhere that an integer can be stored.

The compiler has to do things totally differently to access `extern int *arr;` from `extern int arr[];`.

As written, the most likely result is a crash as the compiler dereferences a null pointer.  The behaviour is undefined, though, and anything is possible.  You've lied to the compiler; the compiler will get its own back — it does not like being lied to.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are not pointers.

`arr` is defined to be an array so declare it as an array as well.

```
extern int arr[10];   // file2.c
```

If you don't, your program invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: But why does this happen that if we declare it as pointer then undefined behaviour?

Comment: Because the two types are different and C says if you don't use the correct type your program invokes behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In the `int arr[10];` form, `arr` itself does not occupy memory space; it is just an address value that can be determined at link time. Suppose `arr` is 100; `arr[0]` is the value in memory address 100.

In the `extern int *arr;` form, `arr` itself is a variable in memory. Suppose arr is 100, `arr[0]` is the value in memory address `ptr`, while `ptr` is the value of memory cell at address 100.

**EDIT**

The asm generated by gcc gives a deep insight:

```
extern int a[10];
extern int *b;

int foo(void)
{
    return a[3] + b[5];
}

_foo:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp

    movl    _b, %eax /* 1st memory load for pointer */
    addl    $20, %eax
    movl    (%eax), %eax /* 2nd memory load for pointer  */

    addl    _a+12, %eax /* only one memory load for array */

    popl    %ebp
    ret
```

Comment: Using the `<kbd>` ... `</kbd>` notation to surround code is unorthodox.  Please use the regular code-in-back-ticks notation.