# Difference between array and pointer versions of external declarations

Tags: c, declaration, extern

Are the following same:

```
extern int a[];
```

and

```
extern int *a;
```

I mean, are they interchangable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing the value of an external variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433953/changing-the-value-of-an-external-variable)

Comment: May be this help you: [Difference between `char *str` and `char str[]` and how both stores in memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177420/what-does-sizeofarray-return/15177499#15177499)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No they are not.  You'll see the difference when you try something like `a++`.

There's plenty of questions about the difference between pointers and arrays, I don't think it's necessary to write more here.  Look it up.

Answer (score 1):

They are not the same. The first:

```
extern int a[];
```

declares an array of `int`. The second

```
extern int *a;
```

declares a pointer to `int`. As the [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html) states:

```
The array declaration "char a[6]" requests that space for six characters be set aside, 
to be known by the name "a". That is, there is a location named "a" at which six 
characters can sit. The pointer declaration "char *p", on the other hand, requests a 
place which holds a pointer, to be known by the name "p". This pointer can point 
almost anywhere: to any char, or to any contiguous array of chars, or nowhere.
```

This causes a difference in how the compiler behaves:

```
It is useful to realize that a reference like "x[3]" generates different code 
depending on whether "x" is an array or a pointer. Given the declarations above, when 
the compiler sees the expression "a[3]", it emits code to start at the location "a", 
move three past it, and fetch the character there. When it sees the expression "p[3]", 
it emits code to start at the location "p", fetch the pointer value there, add three 
to the pointer, and finally fetch the character pointed to. In other words, a[3] is 
three places past (the start of) the object named a, while p[3] is three places 
past the object pointed to by p.
```

You'll have unexpected behavior if you use `extern int *a` if `a` is actually an array. Given the expression `a[3]`, the compiler will treat the first element of `a` as an address and try to get the element three places past that address. If you're lucky, the program will crash; if you're not, some data will be corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

```
extern int a[];
```

is an array object

```
extern int *a;
```

is a pointer that could be pointed to  an array of int

See the above links for more information concerning difference between pointer and array object

[*(a++) is giving error but not *(a+1)?? where a is array name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16456197/a-is-giving-error-but-not-a1-where-a-is-array-name/16456221#16456221)

Comment: You mean pointed to the integer that is first element of an array, right? Not array itself? Since array is an adress of int itself...

Answer (score 0):

When you see `extern int a[]` it tells you that somewhere (may be in other file) is declared an array  of integers, while `extern int * a` tells you that you have pointer to an integer declared somewhere else and you wish to use it here. There are more differences but that would be another topic.